# Scrolling UILabel like a marquee in a subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I have a UILabel in the main view with text - **"Very Very long text"**. The proper width to this would be 142, but i've shortened it to 55.

Basically I want to implement a marquee type scroll, so I wrote code to add it onto a subview and animate it within the bounds of that view.

**CODE** --

```
    CGRect tempLblFrame = _lblLongText.frame;
    UIView *lblView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:tempLblFrame];

    //Add label to UIView at 0,0 wrt to new UIView
    tempLblFrame.origin.x = 0;
    tempLblFrame.origin.y = 0;

    [_lblLongText setFrame:tempLblFrame];
    [_lblLongText removeFromSuperview];
    [lblView addSubview:_lblLongText];

    //SetClipToBounds so that if label moves out of bounds of its superview, it wont be displayed
    [lblView setClipsToBounds:YES];
    [lblView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor cyanColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:lblView];
```

After this I get this output on the simulator --> [image]

The problem occurs when i try the Animation with this code -

```
    tempLblFrame.origin.x = -_lblLongText.intrinsicContentSize.width;        
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         [_lblLongText setFrame:tempLblFrame];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         NSLog(@"completed");
                     }];
```

I was hoping I would see the entire "Very Very long text", rather only "Very..." scrolls from left to right.

**To solve this** I added one line of code --

```
    //Add label to UIView at 0,0 wrt to new UIView
    tempLblFrame.origin.x = 0;
    tempLblFrame.origin.y = 0;

    tempLblFrame.size.width = _lblLongText.intrinsicContentSize.width; //THIS LINE WAS ADDED

    [_lblLongText setFrame:tempLblFrame];
    [_lblLongText removeFromSuperview];
    [lblView addSubview:_lblLongText];
```

I thought the full text will be set inside the newly added UIView and it would scroll properly. But running in the simulator gave me this --

[image]

And again, only "Very..." was scrolling from left to right.

What am I doing wrong? Please help!!

> > ### EDIT
> >
> > Apparently the culprit was AutoLayout.
>
> I have no clue why, but once I unchecked "Use Autolayout" for the view
>   in the XIB, everything started working as expected. Setting
>   tempLblFrame.origin.x = -_lblLongText.intrinsicContentSize.width; was
>   working properly and so was the scroll.
>
> Any explanation on this!!?

Comment: why you are not using opensource control which has everything fixed? https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel

Comment: Firstly I wanted to try something on my own. Secondly, I have to make changes to an existing project, which has a lot of labels. Instead of removing each label from each xib (both iPad, iPhone), i wanted to try an alternative which will take less effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the culprit was AutoLayout.

I have no clue why, but once I unchecked "Use Autolayout" for the view in the XIB, everything started working as expected. Setting `tempLblFrame.origin.x = -_lblLongText.intrinsicContentSize.width;` was working properly and so was the scroll.

Still, a better explanation for this would surely help!!

### EDIT: Solution with AutoLayout -

```
    //Make UIView for Label to sit in
    CGRect tempLblFrame = _lblLongText.frame;
    UIView *lblView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:tempLblFrame];

    //#CHANGE 1 Removing all constraints 
    [_lblLongText removeConstraints:_lblLongText.constraints]; 

    //Add label to UIView at 0,0 wrt to new UIView
    tempLblFrame.origin.x = 0;
    tempLblFrame.origin.y = 0;
    //Set Full length of Label so that complete text shows (else only truncated text will scroll)
    tempLblFrame.size.width = _lblLongText.intrinsicContentSize.width;

    //#CHANGE 2 setting fresh constraints using the frame which was manually set 
    [_lblLongText setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints :YES];
    [_lblLongText setFrame:tempLblFrame];
    [_lblLongText removeFromSuperview];
    [lblView addSubview:_lblLongText];
```

Answer (score 5):

This question is possibly [Duplicate of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551897/autoscroll-marquee-label-in-iphone).

Although there is nice code snippet written by Charles Powell for [MarqueeLabel](https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel),

also take a look at [This link](http://blog.stormyprods.com/2009/10/simple-scrolling-uilabel-for-iphone.html).

I hope this will help you and will save your time by giving a desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `UILabel` the width (or longer) of the text and the `UIView` the scroll area you want to see. Then set the `UIView`'s `clipToBounds` to `YES` (which you are doing). Then when you animate left to right you will only see the the text the width of the `UIView`, since it is cutting any extra subviews. Just make sure you scroll the entire length of the `UILabel`.

Right now you are setting the view and label's height and width to the same thing. This is why you are getting clipped text, not a clipped label.

Comment: I want the width of the view to remain of the same length. As i mentioned in a comment above, I have to make changes to a lot of labels in a big project and I dont want to change the sizes in UI. And if the text is longer than the designate size, I want it to scroll.

Comment: You don't want to change the sizes in IB? A UILabel cannot scroll, so the minute you place text into it, it will either shrink the text or clip it (adding the ...'s). You will end up needing to change something and I would recommend the label's width, probably the easiest thing.

Comment: I have tried without the temporary UIView. I added a small UILabel with long text. This clipped the text as expected. Later on I programmatically increased the width, and I could see the entire text. There has to be a fix here.

Comment: Why does the text shift like crazy to the right when I added the `tempLblFrame.size.width = _lblLongText.intrinsicContentSize.width;` without changing the origin OR textAlignment.

Comment: I don't really see where you are setting that contentSize but I am guessing it is because UILabel's center their text by default. So if the contentSize is set really large it would shift to the right (to center itself)

Answer (score 0):

You add In your view scrollview and add this label in your scroll view .Use this code

```
 scroll.contentSize =CGSizeMake(100 *[clubArray count],20);
NSString  *bname;
bname=@"";
for(int i = 0; i < [clubArray count];  i++)
{
    bname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %@ ,",bname,[[clubArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"bottle_name"]];
    [bname retain];

}
UILabel *lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[lbl1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0,5,[clubArray count]*100,20)];
lbl1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
lbl1.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
lbl1.userInteractionEnabled=YES;    
[scroll addSubview:lbl1];
lbl1.text= bname;
```

This is implemented code.Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry Darshan, but i dont seem to understand the code. What are the variables - "scroll", "clubArray"? Also keep in mind that I already have UILabels in my XIB. So i wrote code to pick them up from the **main view** and add them on top a **temporary subview** to scroll in. So I want to avoid `[[UILabel alloc] init]`

Comment: this code for custom generate label and that label add in scroll view and automatically generate with the use of my clubarray .so i suggest u use dynamically label.Thanks